# What happens if I create an object of a class A but there also exist a duplicate class of A with same name?

Tags: oop, system-verilog

So I created and object of a class, lets say class A. Now there is also a duplicate class of A already existing. I want to know from which class the object will be created? original or duplicate?

```
class A
definition
end class A

class A
definition
end class A    //These are duplicate classes

A a;
```

So, from which class the object 'a' will be created?

Comment: You can't create two classes with same name in the same file! Even if you create in different files, you won't be able to use both at once without changing name of any one of the class.

Comment: I don't know if we can do it in system verilog, but in most languages you can't. And why would anyone do that? Let's assume even if you can actually create classes with same name, why don't you try having a method with same name in both the classes and try invoking it and check what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two classes with same name in the same *scope*. This is no good:

```
module M;

  class A;
    int i;
  endclass

  class A;
    int i;
  endclass   //These are duplicate classes

  initial
    begin
      A a;
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3sV3

You can have two classes declared with the same name if there are declared in different scopes, however. A package is a scope (which is why you navigate into a package using the *scope resolution operator* - `::`). So, you can do this:

```
package P1;

  class A;
    int i;
  endclass

endpackage

package P2;

  class A;
    int i;
  endclass

endpackage
```

but, you'll find you can't import both into the same scope using the wildcard operator (`*`), because one declaration will hide the other. So, this won't work:

```
module M;

  import P1::*;
  import P2::*;

  initial
    begin
      A a;
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3Khe

Instead, you have to be specific about which declaration of class `A` you want to use. If it's the one in package `P1`, then you can do:

```
module M;

  initial
    begin
      P1::A a;
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/62ba

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in SystemVerilog. You will get an error message from the compiler:

vcs:

> Error-[CRE] Class redefinition encountered

nc:

> ncvlog: *E,DUPIDN (testbench.sv,7|8): identifier 'A' previously declared [12.5(IEEE)].

aldec:

> ERROR VCP7801 "Duplicated declaration of unit A." "testbench.sv" 7  10